# how does jvm allocate memroies when creating array with non literal size

Tags: java, jvm

In c/c++, it is a must to specifiy a literal number of the array size when creating, i.e. `int arr[10];`. But in java, we can create an array in this form `int size = 10; int[] arr = new int[size];`. And the compiler will not figure out what actually the variable size is. Then how does jvm allocate the memeories the array needs ?

Comment: You can do `int *arr = new int[10]` in c/c++, too.

Comment: The array size never had to be a “literal number”; any other constant expression has been sufficient as well. Besides that, since C99 or (afaik) C++14, array creation expressions do not require constant sizes, even on the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java allocates the array memory on the heap. The variable `arr` is just a reference to the array, not the array itself. This is the same as allocating an array in c/c++ with `malloc` or `new`.

Answer (score 0):

In JVM based languages, Java being the most popular, memory allocation happens at runtime, usually on the heap.  However, there are ways to get off-heap memory allocation, which have to be handled by the application itself, and can never be garbage-collected or cause additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

In `int arr[10];` array is determine the size at compile time and in `int size = 10; int[] arr = new int[size];` array is determine the size at run time. you can also create dynamic array in c++ which create on run time.

**Detail :**

In c++,

`int arr[10];` this array is allocated on stack and decide the size of an array on compile time

`int *arr = new int[10];` this array allocated on heap and decide the size of an array  on run time.

In Java, array is always created with `new` keyword and they created on Heap.

```
int[] arr = new int[size];
```

`int[] arr` is the reference to an integer array in java and in C++ `int *arr`is a pointer to an integer array. So, you can also achieve this in c++.